# Python: using while or for loop to iterate through an lists

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I am trying to connect values in tuples in a list without using a dictionary. Specifically, I have this list:

```
adjList = [('0', '3'), ('1', '0'), ('3', '2'), ('4', '2'), ('5', '4'), ('7', '9'), 
('8', '7'), ('9', '6'), ('2', '1'), ('2', '6'), ('6', '5'), ('6', '8')]
```

and I would like to create a list with the values from a random tuple:

```
newList = ['1', '0']
```

then append the second value of a tuple from adjList if the first value of that tuple is the same as the last value of newList, thus:

```
newList = ['1', '0', '3']
```

Then delete ('1', '0') and ('0', '3') from adjList.

THEN I want to repeat this action until the last value in newList NO LONGER corresponds to the first value of a tuple from adjList. I am having a lot of trouble figuring out a logical combination of while or for loops that can do this, and any help would be appreciated.

My code so far:

```
adjList = [('0', '3'), ('1', '0'), ('3', '2'), ('4', '2'), ('5', '4'), ('7', '9'), 
('8', '7'), ('9', '6'), ('2', '1'), ('2', '6'), ('6', '5'), ('6', '8')]

firstNode = random.choice(adjList)
newList = []
newList.append(firstNode[0])
newList.append(firstNode[1])
adjList.remove(firstNode)

## I need to repeat the following block of code:

for ax,bx in adjList:
    if newList[-1] == ax:
        adjList.remove((ax,bx))
        newList.append(bx)
        break
```

Everything works the way it should, but of course I am only getting 3 values in newList at the end. I can't quite work out how to repeat that final block of code until I run out of tuples in adjList.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What about the case where there are many possible tuples to select from `adjList`? Let's say that randomly selected tuple is `('9', '6')` what would be the correct value of `newList`?

Comment: The correct value of newList would then be ['9', '6', '5']. It is fine to just take the first tuple with the matching value.

Comment: I guess it would be easier to debug if you would not choose a random node.

Comment: The random node has nothing to do with the block of code that I need to repeat, though. Think of it just as the two starting lists if that's easier: adjList as posted, and newList = ['1', '0'], then I need to go from there, matching values and adding them to newList.

Answer (score 1):

You could just run the outer `while` loop while there are items still on the `adjList`. The inner loop could pick the first suitable item from `adjList` and append the result to `newList`. In case the inner loop can't find suitable item the outer loop should be terminated.

Here's a sample of the above:

```
import random

adjList = [('0', '3'), ('1', '0'), ('3', '2'), ('4', '2'), ('5', '4'), ('7', '9'),
('8', '7'), ('9', '6'), ('2', '1'), ('2', '6'), ('6', '5'), ('6', '8')]

newList = list(adjList.pop(random.randint(0, len(adjList) - 1)))

while adjList:
    for i, (src, dest) in enumerate(adjList):
        if src == newList[-1]:
            del adjList[i]
            newList.append(dest)
            break
    else:
        break

print('Result: {}'.format(newList))
print('Remaining: {}'.format(adjList))
```

Output:

```
Result: ['4', '2', '1', '0', '3', '2', '6', '5', '4']
Remaining: [('7', '9'), ('8', '7'), ('9', '6'), ('6', '8')]
```

Comment: This is also a great solution to my problem! Thanks so much, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure whether the following code will apply to your needs, but I think you should be able do what you want with very few changes to your code.

I've added a `while` loop that runs every time there's a change in the structure (basically, every time that a tuple whose first item matches the last item in `newList`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random

adjList = [('0', '3'), ('1', '0'), ('3', '2'), ('4', '2'), ('5', '4'), ('7', '9'),
           ('8', '7'), ('9', '6'), ('2', '1'), ('2', '6'), ('6', '5'), ('6', '8')]

firstNode = random.choice(adjList)
newList = []
newList.append(firstNode[0])
newList.append(firstNode[1])

changes_made = True
while changes_made:
    changes_made = False
    for item in adjList:
        if item[0] == newList[-1]:
            newList.append(item[-1])
            adjList.remove(item)
            changes_made = True
            break

print newList
```